# Hive 0.13.0, partition and buckets

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting an error message, which is very different from 2 test runs.

I verified data types data and exactly - double value but there is an issue with type cast.

Why does this occur?, please help me to fix

```
DROP TABLE XXSCM_SRC_SHIPMENTS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  XXSCM_SRC_SHIPMENTS(
  INVENTORY_ITEM_ID            DOUBLE
 ,ORDERED_ITEM                 STRING
 ,SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID             DOUBLE
 ,QTR_START_DATE               STRING
 ,QTR_END_DATE                 STRING
 ,SEQ                          DOUBLE
 ,EXTERNAL_SHIPMENTS           DOUBLE
 -- ,PREV_EXTERNAL_SHIPMENTS      DOUBLE
 ,INTERNAL_SHIPMENTS           DOUBLE
 --,PREV_INTERNAL_SHIPMENTS      DOUBLE
 ,AVG_SELL_PRICE               DOUBLE)
 --,PREV_AVG_SELL_PRICE          DOUBLE)
 COMMENT 'DIMENTION FOR THE SHIPMENTS LOCAL AND GLOBAL'
 PARTITIONED BY (ORGANIZATION_CODE STRING, FISCAL_PERIOD   STRING)
 CLUSTERED BY (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, ORDERED_ITEM, SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID, QTR_START_DATE, QTR_END_DATE, SEQ) 
 SORTED BY (INVENTORY_ITEM_ID ASC, ORDERED_ITEM ASC, SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID ASC, QTR_START_DATE ASC, QTR_END_DATE ASC, SEQ ASC) 
 INTO 256 BUCKETS
 STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");

1) Error Fails
     SELECT  inventory_item_id,ordered_item,ship_from_org_id,qtr_start_date,qtr_end_date,seq,external_shipments FROM supply_chain_pcam.XXSCM_SRC_SHIPMENTS limit 100


Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable



2) Got the result successfully
    hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from supply_chain_pcam.xxscm_src_shipments limit 100"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID field. You will need to re-create the table XXSCM_SRC_SHIPMENTS with the correct data type. Hive is not able to parse that field. You almost had the answer - if

```
select *
```

is fetching the result then try-out individual fields - Here it says a cast exception to double so you can take only the double fields.

Comment: Hi,I have tried and looked at field original source attribute data type is Double when i load from original source to my table succeeds and on `select` fileds is failing....there is no problem as i see..but it  should fail even on `select *` if the same behaviour

Comment: Try `select distinct SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID from <source-table>` also `select min(SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID), max(SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID) FROM <source-table>` you will be able to see the data range.

Comment: Hi, This is a bug identified from code base and we fixed it. thanks